# Extract string between curly braces in java

Tags: java

I have String `{a,b,c},{1,2,3}`. How to extract to get like

```
String1 = a,b,c;
String2 = 1,2,3;
```

I have tried someting like this, but that does not work.

```
String result1 = str.substring(str.indexOf("{") + 1, str.indexOf("},"));
String result2 = str.substring(str.indexOf(",{") + 1, str.indexOf("}"));
```

Comment: In the 2nd line, `str.indexOf("}")` returns the index of the first bracket. [`lastIndexOf()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf(int))) would return the index of the last bracket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an `indexOf` method that takes the *index* from which to search

```
String str = "{a,b,c},{1,2,3}";
int startingIndex = str.indexOf("{");
int closingIndex = str.indexOf("}");
String result1 = str.substring(startingIndex + 1, closingIndex);
System.out.println(result1);

startingIndex = str.indexOf("{", closingIndex + 1);
closingIndex = str.indexOf("}", closingIndex + 1);
String result2 = str.substring(startingIndex + 1, closingIndex);
System.out.println(result2);
```

In the second block, we make the search start at `closingIndex + 1` where `closingIndex` is the index of the last seen `}`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression for that e.g.

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(?<=\\{).+?(?=\\})").matcher("{a,b,c},{1,2,3}");
while(m.find()){
   System.out.println(m.group());
   // a,b,c
   // 1,2,3
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible solutions for this task will be using [Pattern class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

It should be a much more elegant solution for getting values between braces.
For matching the first group regex should be: `\{([^}]*)\}`.
Just add a separator between group `,` and repeat regex again. Now you can get results separately.

Here is code demo:

```
public class RegexDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "{a,b,c},{1,2,3}";

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\{([^}]*)\\},\\{([^}]*)\\}");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);

        String first = null;
        String second = null;

        if (matcher.find()) {
            first = matcher.group(1);
            second = matcher.group(2);
        }
        System.out.printf("First: %s\nSecond: %s\n", first, second);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
First: a,b,c  
Second: 1,2,3
```