# How to remove all punctuation except curyl brackets { } in java?

Tags: java, regex, string

We have keys between curly brackets and want to search these keys in some string. But when we split the string like .split(" ") some punctuation stays with the string elements. We tried the `"\\p{P}"` regex but it deleted the curly brackets that we need. So how do we fix this issue?

Many thanks.

```java
String keys =  " Dear {User_Name}, your process..."
List<String> bodyContent = (Arrays.asList(keys.replaceAll("\\p{P}", "").split(" ")));
```

After these `bodyContent = {"Dear" , "User_Name" , ...}`

But we want `"{User_Name}"` instead of `"User_Name"` or `"{User_Name},"`

Comment: Do you just want to extract text from curly braces? See https://stackoverflow.com/a/60417695/3832970 or https://stackoverflow.com/q/12586132/3832970

Comment: No , I just want to remove all punc. except curly brackets

Comment: When you say punctuation, do you mean punctuation proper or (math) symbols included?

Comment: It seems more like you want to replace your keys, try String.replace().

Comment: If you just want to subtract `{}` from `\p{P}`, use `[\p{P}&&[^{}]]` or a simple `[^\P{P}{}]`, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/3201689/3832970

Answer (score -1):

To match all words that might also include any curly brackets you can use the following regex, which:

1. `{*`: matches zero or more lefthand curly brackets.
2. `\w*`: matches zero or more word characters.
3. `}*`: matches zero or more righthand curly brackets.

```
({*\w*}*)
```

I'd suggest using [regex101.com](https://regex101.com) to test or make any changes you may see fit. I also have a link for the regex101 I used [here](https://regex101.com/r/Kx5bze/1).